# hibernate is not storing granular date only midnight

Tags: java, hibernate, date, jdbc

I have a table with a timestamp field in it `entrydate` (Postgres `timestamp without timezone` type), however when it is propagated with hibernate, all of its values seem to be truncated, granularity wise, to just midnight of the current day (well, of the Date set) a la `2013-04-19 00:00:00` how do I get better granularity like seconds, hours, minutes, milliseconds?

hibernate cfg xml file:

```
<class name="Tape" table="Tape">
  <property column="EntryDate" name="EntryDate" type="date"/>`
  ...
 </class>
```

It uses a `java.util.Date` object within the java class `Tape`, with appropriate getters and setters, and they do work for serializing it, it just ends up saving it in the DB without any precision/granularity more than the day itself.

Comment: This question and answer would be much improved if you spoke precisely, specifying *exactly* what data type is your Postgres column and *exactly* what classes you are using including their full package name.

Comment: @BasilBourque good point, question attempted updated

Comment: Still not precise. Postgres has two different [data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) with the word "timestamp". Java has two different classes with the word "Date".

Comment: @BasilBourque precision added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that "date" in hibernate is "just the day, not the hour" unlike a java Date class, which has millisecond granularity.

Fix was to use hibernate timestamp instead:

`<property column="EntryDate" name="EntryDate" type="timestamp"/>`

now it has millisecond granularity in the DB.

Comment: You should accept your own answer, you'll get a badge.